# Chrome Browser Action click not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to create chrome extension, however my [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) click does not work! I've tried pretty much everything. Here is my setup:

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "blah",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "blah",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon1.png",
  "popup": "popup.html"
 },  
"permissions": [
  "bookmarks",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*", 
  "https://*/*"    
],
"background_page": "background.html"
}
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<!-- Try adding the listener in popup.html  -->
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab){
    console.log("Hello from popup"); // This does not show up either
    } );
 </script>
</head><body>
 Hello
</body>
</html>
```

background.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
console.log("Background.html"); // This gets displayed. O.K.

function hello() {
  console.log("HELLO"); // THIS NEVER GETS DISPLAYED
}

// Supposed to Called when the user clicks on the browser action icon.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(hello); 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

But no matter how hard i click on the Icon nothing happens and "HELLO" is not printed out in the console!

I am using Chrome 4.0.249.43. I installed the Beta version BUT it is exactly the same as the released version (same verion number). Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You cannot have a "popup" with an onclick event. Remove the popup.html from the manifest file. And keep the background page, and it will work.

Comment: That is correct. Popup completely eliminates the onclick event! Took me two days to figure that out.

Comment: Did anyone on the Chrome extension team ever hear of POLA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Chrome's extension documentation sucks

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a workaround to have a popup that can do something to the current tab? For example I click the popup icon, select a color, and it changes the current tabs background color.

Comment: It is now included in the [documentation](http://localhost:8080/docs/extensions/reference/action/#popup).

Comment: @MichaelYimam that link goes to localhost. Try this link [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#popup)

Answer (score 9):

I found the root cause with my problem on :-
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked)

> **browser​Action​.onClicked:-** Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.

removed the deafult_popup from manifest.json

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```

Comment: They couldn't document that neat little detail any less prominent ...

Answer (score 5):

You need delete the popup.html, you already have a popup in popup.html in theory the background.html should do the event for browserAction but is wrong. When you clicked in the Icon of you app there's already defined an function onClicked in popup.

i dont know for what you need, but you can make many functions when you clicked in the browser.

For example: in background.html do:

```
 foo(){
        if(browserAction && browserAction.onClicked) // you can add all stuff that you need.
        do something
    }
```

and you call from popup.html with chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().foo();

well i hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems too while trying to create a chrome extension. Make sure you reload the extension after any change to the manifest.json or the background page. To reload it, go to the extensions page (wrench>tools>extensions) and choose reload. That might just be the cause of the problem, everything else seems just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're viewing the correct JavaScript console for the background page, and not for the other tab?

Try having your hello() method set a global variable in the background page, then have a button in popup.html retrieve that variable (using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()) and display it as an alert.

Comment: Hi, i edited to show that I tried adding the listener to the popup.html and it doesn't work either...

Answer (score -1):

According to the [doc](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(Tab tab) {...});
```

so:

```
// Supposed to be called when the user clicks on the browser action icon.    
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    hello();
});
```

should work

Comment: Since he never used or called `tab`, and never used context (`this`), this would make no difference...